# Central heating drain valve won't shut

Tags: leak, drain, valve

Today I drained my central heating/hot water system. This is a standard vented, pumped S plan with two electric valves and an indirect hot water cylinder, and I'm in UK.

I was lucky enough to have a drain valve underneath ground floor, relatively accessible, see pics:

[image]

So I opened it and was able to drain: good!
However, upon refilling the system, I found out that that valve will rotate endlessly, and won't guarantee proper isolation: it's stripped.

I was thinking to add an isolating (aka service) valve past the old one, i.e., along the pipe in the bottom part of the images.

Something like this: 
[image]

Do you think that will work? Or is there a risk that the old valve will leak when the new one is shut? Do you foresee any other possible problem?

Any feedback welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: For those of us not in the UK, would you mind [edit]ing your post to describe what a "CH/HW" is. Also, did your work involve turning the valve in question, or was it left alone?

Comment: Thank you! I don't have an answer for you, but at least now I know what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding one of those isolators is a good plan.

I used to put one inline with every tap as they are cheap and make subsequent maintenance easy - less draining of the whole system.